# Help with an entity-relationship diagram re Manager entity type and its relationships

Tags: database-design, erd

In the below ER diagram:

- A manager can have many Users but a User can only have 1 Manager
- A Manager must be able to assign multiple users to multiple courses

Are the manager relationships correct?

[image]

Comment: Are you certain you don't need to add a layer for course session?  i.e. separate course description from course schedule?

Comment: Thanks  @Ray. Would the Course_Assigned table do that job?  As it is online courses this would include assigned_start_date and assigned_end_date - i.e. the start date of course depends on when the manager has assigned the course

Comment: It certainly could.  As John said below you would need to add session related columns (SessionId, Schedule info, etc.)  Basically it would become a many-2-many mapping table.  A course could have multiple sessions and a session would have multiple students.

Answer (score 1):

One issue with this design is allowing for a user to have more than one course at a time. A way to work this is to have a join table between the User table and the Courses table, with only three columns: Join_id, Course_id, User_id. The relationship between users and managers looks good to me, with many users being assigned only one manager each.
Regarding one of the comments; adding to the Course_Assigned table a few fields that include a session_id, start_date, and end_date could be used to directly connect a user to a particular session.